# Python - copy.deepcopy() doesn't work on copying local scope into global scope variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is a portion of code from my latest project.

```
import copy

chg = None

def change(obj):
    print("obj =", obj)
    chg = copy.deepcopy(obj)
    #chg = obj
    print("chg = obj =", chg)

class B():

    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, 'example_member', "CHANGED!")
        self.configure()

    def configure(self):
        global chg
        change(self.example_member)
        print("chg on inside =", chg)

b = B()
print("print chg on global =", chg)
```

So the thing is, I was expecting global `chg` to changes it values from `None` to `obj`'s value.

So I was expecting below output :

```
obj = CHANGED!
chg = obj = CHANGED!
chg on inside = CHANGED!
print chg on global = CHANGED!
```

However, it came to my surprise that global `chg` identifier doesn't change at all. Below is the output produces by above code.

```
obj = CHANGED!
chg = obj = CHANGED!
chg on inside = None
print chg on global = None
```

So what I need to do in order to do the global `chg` with local scoped `obj`/`example_member` object value? I'm new to Python so some explanation might as do good to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `chg` as `global` in the `change()` function, otherwise it is local.  An assignment inside a function to a name not declared as `global` *within the function* defaults the new variable to local scope.

```
def change(obj):
    global chi                       # <<<<< new line
    print("obj =", obj)
    chg = copy.deepcopy(obj)
    #chg = obj
    print("chg = obj =", chg)
```

Gives:

```
obj = CHANGED!
chg = obj = CHANGED!
chg on inside = CHANGED!
print chg on global = CHANGED!
```

However it would be better to avoid using a global like this.

Comment: What is a better way? How about if I need an object that needs to works across a lot of modules? I can't think of any other cleaner way than making the object global or static. Passing the object over module to module look hard to maintenance.

Comment: By the way, I'm currently working with Python with Pyside. I need to pass the object that relates to specific widget across all modules. Any guides for this kind of job that doesn't need any global variables? :)